# How to create a cron-job on AWS without lambda nor endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I am trying to achieve these:

- deploy a spring-boot application on AWS, which does something, say,
  print the current system time; and
- the application runs as a cron-job on AWS, for example, every 1st day of a month; and
- no endpoint (URL) is exposed by the application.

How to implement that? Any code snippets or guidance will be highly appreciated.

(I searched the web and the solutions are mostly to create a lambda or set the target of the cron-job to be an endpoint. But none of them is what I want.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule an event using [Event Bridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) but that should have an (internal) service endpoint as a target.  (Not sure from your question why that is a problem.)

Alternatively, you can always spin up an EC2 instance, deploy your application on it, and then set up a `crontab -e` on it.  Will be more expensive, but will have no endpoint.

Combining the two, you could schedule an EventBridge event that will kick off a lambda that will kick off a CloudFormation deployment to spin up an EC2 instance with your application, which on completion will kick off a lambda to tear down the CloudFormation stack and terminate your instance so that you have to pay for EC2 only while it is running.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like EC2 is the only choice other than lambda. Right? The reason that I do not want an endpoint is that the application will be a background service and, in our system, background service cannot have endpoint.

Comment: @leo how long does the spring-boot application runs on average and how often do you need to run it?

Comment: I have added a third possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eventbridge to schedule a cron & then for target choose the service on which you have deployed the your application

Comment: I do not want to expose any endpoint from the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBridge scheduler to send an SQS message to an SQS queue. You can then listen to the SQS queue and consume the message and treat it as a cronjob.